1970s movie where a man kisses girl and the girl turns into a corpse
I remember having seen this on German TV in the beginning of the 1980s or maybe at the end of the 1970s.  I'm pretty sure it was a movie originally shown in cinemas, so it must have been a few years old when it was aired on TV.  (For some reason I think it was maybe a French movie, but I'm not sure about that.)
The only scene I remember features a man and a woman (clearly younger than the man) kissing and it looks as if they are about to sleep with one another.  The woman is naked or at least partially undressed.  The two are standing in front of a mirror.  Suddenly, the man realizes (maybe from the mirror image) that the young girl has turned into a kind of cadaver of an old woman.  He backs off in shock.
I remember vividly that this scene made a big impression on me, but I forgot pretty much anything else.  Any idea which movie this might have been?

Sounds like The Shining

Did the scene look like this?  https://imgur.com/87Y6PGT

It's probably The Shining, but there's a similar scene in Ghost Story.

Basically sounds like the green bathroom scene in The Shining:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Shining_(film)
The Shining is a 1980 film made by Stanley Kubrick.
When the scene happens that you describe, the main characters son has gone into Room 237 at this hotel, and has returned not unscathed. The father investigates and instead finds the bathroom of said room occupied by a young attractive and very naked lady. She goes to him, they embrace, kiss, and at this point he notices something very wrong with her.

In the mirror, the character can see that what he is embracing is not what he thought it was:

The following points are seen in this scene of the movie:

a man and a woman (clearly younger than the man) kissing
The woman is naked or at least partially undressed.
The two are standing in front of a mirror.
Suddenly, the man realizes (maybe from the mirror image) that the young girl has turned into a kind of cadaver of an old woman.
He backs off in shock.


Thanks, the scene perfectly fits my description.  I'm close to marking this as the accepted answer.  But my problem is that I'm pretty sure I saw "The Shining" in a movie theater first and I think the film was shown on German TV several years after 1980.  This somehow doesn't fit with my recollection of where and when I saw this on TV.  Sigh, probably my memory doesn't work that well anymore...
